# In what emergency situations would a pilot bail out of a helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, emergency, emergency-procedures, parachute, ejection-seat

[The Hiller UH-12 POH](http://www.helihiller.com/manuals/UH-12C_FlightManual.pdf) actually mentions “Emergency Exit in Flight” as an emergency procedure. What emergencies would make the pilot do this and why don’t other helicopter POH’s mention this?

Comment: This is exactly why no helicopters use parachute any more.

Comment: Erin, what helicopters are you familiar with where the crew routinely wear parachutes?  I flew them in the 80's and 90's and never wore one.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast the UH-12 manual linked mentions unbuckling the parachute harness when ditching, so apparently parachutes were worn at the time.

Comment: I fly a light airplane very often, with no parachute, and have never felt the need of one. And I'm not alone in doing this. In the airfield where I have my plane, I have never seen a parachute...

Comment: @jwenting were Hillers typically flown above 1000' agl?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't know. But that's what the flight manual says to do in case of ditching :) May well have SOP for pilots to wear parachutes in military aircraft at the time, and it just carried over despite being useless, who knows.

Comment: @jwenting Ditching is flying or landing the helicopter into the water and then getting out.  Bailing out means you abandon the aircraft while it is flying, and you use a parachute.  If you aren't at least 500' AGL you are usually dead on impact before the chute deploys.  Depends on the chute and how quickly you get the D ring pulled.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast irrelevant. I know what ditching is :) Fact is, the POH says to detach the parachute harness prior to ditching, indicating that one was used. That's the only relevant bit here, not the difference between ditching and bailing out.

Answer (score 6):

One example of a helicopter bailout that I am aware of was the ditching of a USAF Sikorsky HH-60G during the infamous "[Perfect Storm](https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/30-october-1991/)." After several failed attempts to refuel from a tanker in the extreme weather the pilot decided to ditch. He hovered to allow the other occupants to bail out, but he was unable to bail out himself as the engines flamed out from fuel exhaustion and he autorotated to the water. After it hit the waves it rolled over. At this point he realized that he had not jettisoned his door as per the procedure for bailout or ditching so he was trapped. He managed to escape, but one of the other crew was lost at sea.

Comment: Tom, did the 'bail out' include a parachute?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast No parachutes. Most of the crew were rescue swimmers. They jumped from low altitude. But the waves were so high that if they didn't time it right at the crest they fell like 40 feet to the water.